# unpacking nested loops from list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

need to know the following list comprehension.

```
return [x for g in alist for x, R in aux(g) for I in R]
```

Can plz someone write the above code in simple loops instead of comprehension so I can understand how it works.Thanks

Comment: You can find the answer here https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/

Answer (score 2):

It helps to read comprehensions backwards in groups of the `for` keyword. You start with the outer-most loop *(left)* which is `for g in alist` then move inwards *(right)* in groups of `for`

```
result = []
for g in alist:
    for x, R in aux(g):
        for I in R:
            result.append(x)
```

Or if below helps:

```
 for g in alist:
^---
    for x, R in aux(g):
   ^----
        for I in R:
```

That's how the comprehension is made.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? `print([(a, b) for a in range(2) for b in range(2)])` for example would print `[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]`

Comment: I tried your code and it gave the following error.                                                                        UnboundLocalError: local variable 'R' referenced before assignment

Comment: @j1-lee You're right. but rather poor example using the same ranges

Comment: Your answer is opposite of your description of "You start with the outer-most loop (rightmost) which is for I in R then move inwards (left) in groups of for".